# Method call with option value or default parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, default, higher-order-functions, scala-option

I'm rather new to Scala and stumbled upon a small little issue that keeps bothering me. Let's say there is some method with default parameter

```
def foo(v: Any = "default"): String = s"called with parameter '$v'"
```

and an Option `val opt: Option[String]`.
How to call this method with either the option value (if defined) or the default parameter?
I mean despite the obvious solution

```
val result = if (opt.isDefined)
               from.here.to.foo(opt.get)
             else
               from.here.to.foo()
```

and having to type the method with (possibly long) object chain twice? Not to mention having more than one optional/default parameter...

---

All I could come up with is the unhelpful helper

```
def definedOrDefault[A, B](opt: Option[A], f0: => B, f1: A => B): B =
  if (opt.isDefined) f1(opt.get) else f0
```

but when not being able to mention default parameters in higher order functions... that's it. Reminds me of the bad old days with Java where method overloading creates the same problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you are using two concepts of value being optional in one place, i.e. optional parameter and `Option`. They don't like play well together, maybe it is better to use just one.

If you always just pass value of `Option` to a method or pass nothing to get default value, maybe consider changing the function to accept the `Option`.

```
def foo(v: Option[String]) = {
  val param = v getOrElse "default"
  s"called with parameter '$param'"
}
```

If you still want to have default parameter you can change signature to

```
def foo(v: Option[String] = None)
```

This approach however will require you to wrap your parameter into `Some` when you do a regular call e.g.

```
foo(Some("regular param"))
```

but it works well when you use `Option`s. You can easly add more optional parameters as well.

Here is an example

```
def foo(v1: Option[String] = None, v2: Option[Int] = None) = {
  val param1 = v1 getOrElse "default"
  val param2 = v2 getOrElse 42
  s"'$param1', '$param2'"
}

foo() // "default", 42

foo(v2 = Some(12)) // "default", 12

foo(Some("asd"), Some(11)) // "asd", 11

val optionFromSomewhere = Some("a")
val anotherOptionFromSomewhere = Option.empty[Int]
foo(optionFromSomewhere, anotherOptionFromSomewhere) // "a", 42
```

You could also introduce implicit conversion from `Any` to `Option`, that would let you to omit `Some`, but I don't think it is such a good idea

```
 implicit def any2option[A](e: A): Option[A] = Some(e)
```

Comment: You might even set the "default" parameter in this case to `None` to retain some of the same semantics.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that as well. The answer was work in progress :p

Comment: I was hoping for a solution where the method can be left untouched, it could be part of a library and out of my reach. And checking the parameters first breaks the functional style. But still nice!

Answer (score 2):

Slight extension to @Łukasz's answer which is too large to fit in a comment:

You can avoid having to wrap present parameters in `Some` without the dangerous `any2option` by creating a special-purpose type:

```
sealed trait OptParam[+A] { def toOption: Option[A] }
case class Param[+A](value: A) extends OptParam[A] { def toOption = Some(value) }
case object NoParam extends OptParam[Nothing] { def toOption = None }

object OptParam {
  implicit def any2optParam[A](x: A): OptParam[A] = Param(x)
}

def foo(v1: OptParam[String] = NoParam, v2: OptString[Int] = NoParam) = {
  val param1 = v1.toOption.getOrElse("default")
  val param2 = v2.toOption.getOrElse(42)
  s"'$param1', '$param2'"
}

foo("a") // "'a', '42'"
```

What makes this safer is that `OptParam` should only ever appear as a method parameter type, so the conversion won't get triggered where you don't expect it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` function defined on `Option` to transform the value wrapped inside, if it is defined. This looks like this:

```
opt.map(foo)
// same as
opt.map(x => foo(x))
```

This will return either an `Option[String]` if some value was inside, or `None` if it was `None` before.

Here is the full example from the REPL:

```
scala> def foo(v: Any = "default"): String = s"called with parameter '$v'"
foo: (v: Any)String

scala> Some("Hello")
res0: Some[String] = Some(Hello)

scala> res0.map(foo)
res1: Option[String] = Some(called with parameter 'Hello')

scala> val x: Option[String] = None
x: Option[String] = None

scala> x.map(foo)
res2: Option[String] = None
```

**EDIT:**

To call it with a default value, you should match your Option before your call, since the method expects a non `Option` parameter.

```
val optOrDefault = opt getOrElse "default"
foo(optOrDefault)
```

Comment: I think OP would like to see `"called with parameter default"` when the `Option` is empty. This would require `opt map foo getOrElse foo()`, which is slightly better, but still requires typing `foo` twice and doesn't scale to more optional parameters.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right. I will extend my answer, thanks.